# How to use python async task without await

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I use async create_task to run my task in background, but my_task() method not be executed.

```
async def my_task():
    print("starting my task...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("finished my task.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("1111")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(my_task())
    print("2222")
```

the result is

```
1111
2222
```

Comment: It is not sufficient to call `create_task()`, you need to _run_ the event loop, e.g. using `loop.run_until_complete(my_task())`. Also, you cannot call `time.sleep()`  in an async function, you must `await asyncio.sleep(2)` instead.

Comment: @user4815162342: You *can* call `time.sleep`. You just *really* shouldn't, unless you're trying to simulate CPU-bound work that wouldn't `await` back to the event loop.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Such simulation is misguided because CPU work shouldn't be done in the asyncio thread either, as it will halt the executor. One should off-load such work to another thread or process using `loop.run_in_executor()`.

Comment: @user4815162342: Depends how much of it there is. I'll grant, a two second sleep is simulating entirely too much `await`-less CPU work. But a tenth of a second? Eh, that's within the bounds of reason.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Agreed. The "acceptable" amount of pause without yielding is a matter of some debate in the async world, but it boils down to how much latency it is acceptable to add to an arbitrary IO event that might arrive while the event loop is halted. If the CPU spikes are comparatively rare and the system doesn't have strict latency constraints, then even a 1s pause could be acceptable. Another thing to take into account is that Python has a stop-the-world GC that can have quite large pauses when under load. But I'm digressing...

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple fix for this, but you still need to use await which you cannot avoid because create tasks returns a coroutine

```py
import asyncio

async def my_task():
    print("starting my task...")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("finished my task.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("1111")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(my_task())
    # or use can use asyncio.run(my_task())
    print("2222")
```

EDIT: Made changes for pyfile, instead of notebook, thanks  user4815162342 for pointing out

Comment: `await` won't work at top-level, you must call `asyncio.run()` or `loop.run_until_complete()` instead.

Comment: Good point, i ran this with a notebook, with nest_asycnio.apply()